# Figuring out what link a user clicked in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 4 links a user can click with each one's destination being different but I have a Filter applied to each ActionResult in the Controller that runs a few checks and redirects them to a page with a required form. I am trying to figure out a way to capture what link was clicked and store it in Session so when the user lands on the page the filter redirects to I can create a link back the page s/he was intending to go to. I tried `Request.UrlReferrer` but that simple catches the URL for the page the user was on when s/he clicked the link.

Controller:

```
[NetGalFilter]
public ActionResult Transactions()
{
    return View();
}
```

Filter:

```
public class NetGalFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var Controller = filterContext.Controller as Sprague.RTS.WebUI.Controllers.BaseController;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["HasConfirmed"] == null && Controller.TerminalUserData.IsNetGallonTerminal)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "DataEntry", action = "ConversionFactors" }));
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Request.Url` doesn't give you what you need?

Comment: `Request.Url` give you the current URL so no it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HttpContext` in `filterContext`. There you have the `Request` property which is of type [HttpRequestBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and has the `RawUrl` to get the exact URL from the browser as well as other properties to get the parsed Action and Controllers.

Comment: I am not sure what your getting at here. `Request.UrlReferrer` does not give me the correct URL. I have also tried `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer` but that does not give the URL of the link clicked to trigger the filter it only give the URL the user was on when they clicked the link.

Comment: i wrote `RawUrl` so `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl`. I nowhere mentioned `UrlReferrer` you should read the documentation on [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand that it does something totally different

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your posting. I have tested the `RawUrl` and it is giving me the data I need. Thank you very much.